# WiFi disconnects after a period of time

Tags: wifi, release-juno, suspend, laptop, power

Since updating to [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno), from [release-loki](/questions/tagged/release-loki), the [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) disconnects after a period of time (around 15-20 minutes).

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite. I've checked the power settings, and when plugged in the machine is set to never suspend. I didn't have this problem on Loki, so I'm assuming it's a setting I'm not seeing in the Settings, or can be solved by command line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tlp (linux advanced power management) installed?
If the answer is yes you could install the tlpui and disable the power saving mode when in battery, and see if it still happens.

To install tlpui :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlpui
```

Page of reference: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/install-tlpui-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html

Comment: I don’t have tlp installed, but will do so and give that try. Though I leave the laptop plugged in all the time.

Comment: You'll have different configuration modes for battery mode or plugged-in mode.
To save any changes made click on the top left File menu and then save.